# ld: library not found for -llibtbb.dylib

Tags: opencv

I try to compile some files from the opencv-2.4.8/apps/haarfinder but i get the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -llibtbb.dylib
```

Notice the double `l` in the filename.

I try to follow the tutorial here:
http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html

And in the comments i readed:

> After many, many hours of pondering and looking around. I decided to
>   take it as a spelling error in some file so I decided to look into
>   opencv files and search for that "-llibtbb" and finally found it. I
>   corrected it to only "libtbb" and its finally working.

Sadly he didn't mention what file that was.
I tried with sublime 'Find in files' but i can't find it.

Can someone else take a look or help me in another way?
Like if i know where `libtbb.dylib` is stored i might be able to duplicate it and add the spelling error myself.

please help, i'm lost :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose `libtbb.dylib` is in `/usr/local/lib/libtbb.dylib` and `opencv.pc` is in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` (The location may vary depending on where you install `tbb` and `pkg-config`)

Then edit `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc`, change `-llibtbb.dylib` to `/usr/local/lib/libtbb.dylib`

Comment: Thanks, how did you find that? Does this make it a opencv bug?

Comment: This worked for me.  Thanks.  I have no idea how the heck you figured that out.

Comment: this still didn't work for me. I tried it both with and without the - (hyphen) in front but it's not making a difference when installing ros indigo to osx. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I needed it, or rather I found this better solution - and this may help other searchers.

Follow the instructions in the github description, rather than that blog post: https://github.com/mrnugget/opencv-haar-classifier-training

This corrects the spelling error in the command line:

```
g++ `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv | sed 's/libtbb\.dylib/tbb/'`\
  -I. -o mergevec mergevec.cpp\
  cvboost.cpp cvcommon.cpp cvsamples.cpp cvhaarclassifier.cpp\
  cvhaartraining.cpp\
  -lopencv_core -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_objdetect
```

Answer (score 1):

I installed opencv 2.4.12 with tbb from homebrew on El Capitan, and then separately downloaded the source from github in order to compile mergevec and the `s/libtbb\.dylib/tbb/` fix on its own still didn't help.

My fix was to add `-L/usr/local/lib` to the start of the g++ arguments as by default it wasn't searching for my homebrew libs. I *also* had to add `cvsamplesoutput.cpp` as mentioned in another answer to fix the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "IOutput::createOutput(char const*, IOutput::OutputType)", referenced from:
      JpgDatasetGenerator::JpgDatasetGenerator(char const*) in cvhaartraining-8f5a1b.o
      PngDatasetGenerator::PngDatasetGenerator(char const*) in cvhaartraining-8f5a1b.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The final command that worked for me was:

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv | sed 's/libtbb\.dylib/tbb/'`\
  -I. -o mergevec mergevec.cpp  cvboost.cpp cvcommon.cpp cvsamples.cpp\
  cvhaarclassifier.cpp cvhaartraining.cpp cvsamplesoutput.cpp -lopencv_core\
  -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_objdetect
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `libtbb.dylib` file already exists like in my case in the `/usr/local/lib` folder then all you need to do is to run this command:
`export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`

Answer (score 0):

IOutput is an interface where their methods are declared at ioutput.h and must be implemented somewhere. I found out they were implemented at cvsamplesoutput.cpp so we just need ask gcc to compile that file. For that the correct command should be:

```
g++ `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv | sed 's/libtbb\.dylib/tbb/' ` -I. -o mergevec mergevec.cpp cvboost.cpp cvcommon.cpp cvsamples.cpp cvhaarclassifier.cpp cvhaartraining.cpp cvsamplesoutput.cpp -lopencv_core -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_objdetect
```

Comment: Thanks for posting. If I had time I would test if this should be the accepted answer but I have no time :(